# What are proper typings for a function that takes a function as its argument and returns a function that has the same typings as the input function?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a function that takes a function as an argument and then will return a modified version of the same function that was taken as the input. (Note that the function gets changed to a promise).

```
const addLoggerToFunc = (plainFunc) => {
return async (...args) => {
   await doSomeAsyncStuff()
   console.log(`function ${input.name} has been called`);
   plainFunc(...args)
  }
}
```

I want to make sure that typings are not lost once a function has been passed to the `addLoggerToFunc` function.

```
const foo = async (baz: string, bar: number) => {
// ... Do something
}

export const fooWithLogger = addLoggerToFunc(foo)

// I expect fooWithLogger to have the same typings as foo
```

What I tried:

```
const addLoggerToFunc = <T, G>(plainFunc: (...args: T[]) => Promise<G>): ((...args: T[]) => Promise<G>) => {
  return async (...args: T[]) => {
    console.log(`function ${plainFunc.name} has been called`);
    return plainFunc(...args);
  };
};
```

However now `fooWithLogger` has a type of

`const fooWithLogger: (...args: (string | number)[]) => Promise<void>`

instead of

`const fooWithLogger = (baz: string, bar: number) => Promise<void>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const addLoggerToFunc = <T extends any[], G>(plainFunc: (...args: T) => Promise<G>): ((...args: T) => Promise<G>) => {
  return async (...args: T) => {
    console.log(`function ${plainFunc.name} has been called`);
    return plainFunc(...args);
  };
};
```